# How to change default k8s cluster StorageClass with terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

On eks default storage class is called `gp2` and configured with:

```
allow_volume_expansion = false
parameters = {
  "encrypted" = "false"
  "fsType" = "ext4"
  "type" = "gp2"
}
```

and I would like to change the default storage like so:

```
allow_volume_expansion = true
parameters = {
  "encrypted" = "true"
  "fsType" = "ext4"
  "type" = "gp3"
}
```

How can it be done using terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this kubrnetes guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/) I created the following config:

```hcl
# Remove non encrypted default storage class
resource "kubernetes_annotations" "default-storageclass" {
  api_version = "storage.k8s.io/v1"
  kind        = "StorageClass"
  force       = "true"

  metadata {
    name = "gp2"
  }
  annotations = {
    "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "false"
  }
}

# Create the new wanted StorageClass and make it default
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "gp3-enc" {
  metadata {
    name = "gp3-enc"
    annotations = {
      "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "true"
    }
  }
  storage_provisioner = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  volume_binding_mode = "WaitForFirstConsumer"
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  parameters = {
    "encrypted" = "true"
    "fsType" = "ext4"
    "type" = "gp3"
  }
}
```